# How to measure WCF RESTful web service operation performance?

Tags: .net, performance, iis-7.5, wcf-rest, perfmon

I need to measure performance of WCF RESTful web service call (operation duration, peak and average memory and disc usage). How can I do that with `perfmon.exe`?